# PHP forms which contain the £-sign as data, and the £ is convertrd to Â£ in the sent email msgsage?

Tags: php, forms, symbols

Why is a £ symbol in a PHP form entry converted to Â£ in the sent email message?  How can I get it to send just the £ symbol?

Comment: how you send mail?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your e-mail is not correctly encoded.

You can add header `"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"` to your message body.

```
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
```

If you use native `mail()` function $headers array will be the 4th parameter 
`mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)`

Comment: Thank you Timmetje, yes, that certainly fixes the £ sign problem, but I have read that it needs "\r\n" (without the "s), but that seems to upset the formatting for the other parts of the $headers.  I seem to be going round in circles!  Do you have further suggestions?